# Read in a settings file and evaluate in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best way in Node.js to read in a setting file `settings.conf` formatted as a JavaScript object like:

```
  {
     PORT: 443,
     USERNAME: "foo",
     PASSWORD: "bar"
  }
```

And expose those as global variables to the running application. The reading piece is easy with:

```
 var settings = fs.readFileSync('settings.conf');
```

Do I just `eval(settings)` or what is the best way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `eval`, use `JSON.parse`:

```
var settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('settings.conf'));
```

I assume that `settings.conf` is supposed to be JSON, to make it valid, the keys must be wrapped in double quotes:

```
{
    "PORT": 443,
    "USERNAME": "foo",
    "PASSWORD": "bar"
}
```